# TailwindCSS: In a row of cards, make all card images equal height, even when image spans two columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am making a row of cards using TailwindCSS. I want the image that spans two columns in this code to have identical height to the square image that spans one column in desktop.

I've tried using `aspect-ratio` but can't get it to align perfectly. It should scale responsively rather than using a fixed height at different screen widths.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div data-testid="card-row" class="grid md:gap-4 grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3">
  <div
    data-testid="card"
    class="mb-4 grid relative content-start gap-2 lg:gap-4 h-full"
  >
    <a
      class="absolute z-10 inset-0"
      title="Mock title"
      data-testid="content-card-link"
      href="/#"
    ></a>
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="overflow-hidden">
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800"
          alt="Image description 1"
          width="800"
          height="800"
          class="card-module__image__3of09 block transition ease-in-out object-cover w-full h-auto"
          data-testid="content-card-image"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-words prose">
      <p
        class="m-0 font-base-bold text-xs tracking-wider uppercase text-core mb-2"
        data-testid="content-card-eyebrow"
      >
        Mock Eyebrow
      </p>
      <h5
        class="font-heading m-0 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl"
        data-testid="content-card-title"
      >
        Mock title
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    data-testid="card"
    class=" mb-4 grid relative content-start col-span-2 gap-2 lg:gap-4 h-full"
  >
    <a
      class="absolute z-10 inset-0"
      title="Mock title"
      data-testid="content-card-link"
      href="/#"
    ></a>
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="overflow-hidden">
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800"
          alt="Image description 1"
          width="800"
          height="800"
          class="card-module__image__3of09 block transition ease-in-out object-cover w-full h-auto"
          data-testid="content-card-image"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-words prose">
      <p
        class="m-0 font-base-bold text-xs tracking-wider uppercase text-core mb-2"
        data-testid="content-card-eyebrow"
      >
        Mock Eyebrow
      </p>
      <h5
        class="font-heading m-0 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl"
        data-testid="content-card-title"
      >
        Mock title
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need to use an older padding trick technique to the get aspect ratio of the image correct. This is because the `column-gap` between the grid column tracks does not scale, unlike the grid column tracks themselves.

We set the `<img>` element's position container, `.relative`, to have `padding-top: calc(50% - 0.5rem)`. A percentage value for the padding is taken from the *width* of the element. Thus, `50%` will mean that the vertical space will be `50%` of the width, thus getting a 2:1 aspect ratio to (sort of) match the sibling square. However, we need to compensate for the `column-gap`, which is where the `- 0.5rem` comes in, where `0.5rem` is the same as `spacing.2` in default Tailwind configuration.

Then, we add `absolute inset-0 h-full` and remove `h-auto` from the image so that it uses the space generated by our `padding-top` to size itself.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div data-testid="card-row" class="grid md:gap-4 grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3">
  <div
    data-testid="card"
    class="mb-4 grid relative content-start gap-2 lg:gap-4 h-full"
  >
    <a
      class="absolute z-10 inset-0"
      title="Mock title"
      data-testid="content-card-link"
      href="/#"
    ></a>
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="overflow-hidden">
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800"
          alt="Image description 1"
          width="800"
          height="800"
          class="card-module__image__3of09 block transition ease-in-out object-cover w-full h-auto"
          data-testid="content-card-image"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-words prose">
      <p
        class="m-0 font-base-bold text-xs tracking-wider uppercase text-core mb-2"
        data-testid="content-card-eyebrow"
      >
        Mock Eyebrow
      </p>
      <h5
        class="font-heading m-0 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl"
        data-testid="content-card-title"
      >
        Mock title
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    data-testid="card"
    class=" mb-4 grid relative content-start col-span-2 gap-2 lg:gap-4 h-full"
  >
    <a
      class="absolute z-10 inset-0"
      title="Mock title"
      data-testid="content-card-link"
      href="/#"
    ></a>
    <div class="relative" style="padding-top: calc(50% - 0.5rem);">
      <div class="overflow-hidden">
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800"
          alt="Image description 1"
          width="800"
          height="800"
          class="card-module__image__3of09 block transition ease-in-out object-cover w-full h-full absolute inset-0"
          data-testid="content-card-image"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break-words prose">
      <p
        class="m-0 font-base-bold text-xs tracking-wider uppercase text-core mb-2"
        data-testid="content-card-eyebrow"
      >
        Mock Eyebrow
      </p>
      <h5
        class="font-heading m-0 mb-2 font-bold text-2xl"
        data-testid="content-card-title"
      >
        Mock title
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```